Scraping not work in Django and BeautifulSoup
296 / 5.000
Hello, I have a problem when scraping with Django and BeautifulSopup, in the code everything seems to be fine, I point it to a dynamic GeoServer map that is presented on an open web, I work on it for the name of a div but it doesn't bring me What I need, would someone give me a hand? thank you!
#utils.py

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sgainacirsa.ddns.net/cirsa'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    map_div = soup.find('div', class_='map')
    
    if map_div:
        print(map_div)
    else:
        print("No se encontró el div con la clase 'map'.")
else:
    print(f"Error al acceder a la página: {response.status_code}")

#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def index (request):
    return render (request,"index.html")

def scrape_(request):
    url = 'https://sgainacirsa.ddns.net/cirsa'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return render(request, 'scrape.html', {'error': f"Error al realizar la solicitud: {e}"})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        map_div = soup.find('div', class_='map')
        map_content = str(map_div) if map_div else "No se encontró el div con la clase 'map'."
    else:
        map_content = f"Error al acceder a la página: {response.status_code}"

    return render(request, 'scrape.html', {'map_content': map_content})

#HTML Out
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web Scraping con Django</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contenido del div con la clase 'map'</h1>
    <div>
        {{ map_content|safe }}
    </div>
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error }}</div>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>

My project
Original

If I understand correctly, it's better to use:
 soup.find('div', id='map') 

I see here https://sgainacirsa.ddns.net/cirsa/ id='map' is clearly defined.
But in your case it won't help, because this div appears later, after JS is launched. You should use something like selenium, which runs JS before you get the data for scraping.
For example:
#utils.py

from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sgainacirsa.ddns.net/cirsa'
response = HTMLSession().get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    map_div = soup.find('div', id='map')
    
    if map_div:
        print(map_div)
    else:
        print("No se encontró el div con la clase 'map'.")
else:
    print(f"Error al acceder a la página: {response.status_code}")

I use here https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html, outdated but still works:
>python utils.py
<div class="map" id="map" style="height: 900px"></div>


Do I need to install selenium to be able to test this example?

@MartinLudueña  Tu run utils.py from my example I install only  requests_html  and BeautifulSoup4

Sorry, I'm quite new to python and only yesterday I understood what scraping was, how should I show the map? using django where possible? Greetings

to show this map it is not binded with scraping. At first you can add iframe on your web-site. At second you can use API by https://sgainacirsa.ddns.net/geoserver/wspCirsa/wms  to get object layer, drown as IMAGE and https://wms.ign.gob.ar/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ to get background as IMAGE. It is no TEXT information here to scrap. Only images. Probably it is not the best website to scrap something.

Thank you very much, with your help I got to what I needed, how did you find the API?

@MartinLudueña - i simply open "chrome dev tool" (ctrl+shift+i), tab network. And check all sended requests. Some of them are API's calls.

impeccable, thank you very much
